# CircleMarker Multi classname from data

Tags: reactjs, class, geometry

I want to add 3 className from data to CircleMarker, but I only I can add 1 className. Here may code

```
const xxx = [
{ name: 'myname', website: 'mywebsite', city: 'London'}
{ name: 'yourname', website: 'yourwebsite', city: 'Dublin'}

for (let i = 0; i < xxx.length; i++) {

  let nam= xxx[i].name
  let web= xxx[i].website
  let cit= xxx[i].city

       Object.defineProperty(xxx[i], 'objectcircle', {
            value: new L.CircleMarker(xxx[i].geometry, {
                radius: 5,
                fillColor: "black",
                width: 0.5,
                stroke: "black",
                color: '#FFFFF',
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                className: nam web cit
            })
        });
let circle = xxx[i].objectcircle
circle.addTo(map)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it :

```
Object.defineProperty(xxx[i], 'objectcircle', {
            value: new L.CircleMarker(xxx[i].geometry, {
                radius: 5,
                fillColor: "black",
                width: 0.5,
                stroke: "black",
                color: '#FFFFF',
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                className: `${nam} ${web} ${cit}`
            })
        });
```